# How to add more rows to a table/dataframe with increasing dates to a certain date for all value of another column

Tags: python, sql, excel, database, dataframe

I have a table of all countries and their daily record of covid 19 vaccinations. Some countries have records till April 27, 2021, but many do not. So the date columns stop at earlier than April 27 for those countries. My question is how do I add more rows under each country with the date increasing till April 27. Other values can be null. I prefer using Python and SQL. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Where is the data stored now?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: the data is in csv file

Comment: data source: https://www.kaggle.com/gpreda/covid-world-vaccination-progress?select=country_vaccinations.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want using SQL, like this:

```
select c.country, d.date, t.covid_value
from (select distinct country from t) c cross join
     (select distinct date from t) d left join
     t
     on t.country = c.country and t.date = d.date
order by c.country, d.date;
```